# Send push notification using FCM when there is not internet connection

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to various Android smartphones. When the smartphone has internet connection active, all works OK. But if the smartphone not has internet connection, the notification is lost.

My question is, is there a way to send notification when the smartphone recovers internet connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But if the smartphone not has internet connection, the notification is lost.

That's not true. Depending on `collapse_key` settings, messages are stored for later delivery when the target devices has no internet connection.

See [lifetime of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime) docs.

> If the device is not connected to FCM, the message is stored until a connection is established (again respecting the collapse key rules).

Also see [collapsible and non collapsible messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages) and check the `collapse_key` setting options.

Comment: I solved setting "time_to_live": x seconds in the JSON body of the notification. Thanks!

Comment: "time_to_live" also solved the following problem for me: I was sending push notifications regularly, and at some point, I wasn't receiving them anymore, or after a very long delay. Adding `android: { ttl: 20 }` in the message of the notification fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can set Expiration of notification in fire-base console.When the device get internet connection within this range it will get notification. In my opinion there is no settings in mobile devices.

[image]